# Not analysed query on analysed field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have certain document which stores the brand names in analysed form for ex: {"name":"Samsung"}
{"name":"Motion Systems"}. There are cases where i would want a term search starting with "s" which should result in both the documents. and another case where i want only the complete field starting with "s" query which results in only "samsung" returned.
I have analysed the name field and stored it. Is there any way in which i can do the complete field starting with query in elastic search?

Comment: I dont know how people downvote and not even leave a comment on it. May be stackoverflow should ask for a mandatory comment on downvoting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should index your field in two different ways using a [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html). If you tokenize it as you already do you have a match based on the tokens produced by the tokenizer. For the second tye of match that you want you need to either disable analyzing the field and indexing it as it is, or use the [Keywork tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-tokenizer.html) which produce the same result. Your mapping would look like this:

```
{
    "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "brand" : {
                "type" : "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "brand" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed"},
                    "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can search on both fields. When you search on `brand` you get the matches that you already have, while searching on `brand.untouched` you would get the second tye of matches.
There are different ways to put together multiple queries, you can have a look for instance at the [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html).